# Symfony2 conditional service declaration

Tags: symfony, service, mocking, behat

I'm currently trying to find a solid solution to change the dependencies of a Symfony2 service dynamically. In detail: I have a Services which uses a HTTP-Driver to communicate with an external API.

```
class myAwesomeService
{
    private $httpDriver;

    public function __construct(
        HTTDriverInterface $httpDriver
    ) {
        $this->httpDriver = $httpDriver;
    }

    public function transmitData($data)
    {
        $this->httpDriver->dispatch($data);
    } 
}
```

While running the Behat tests on the CI, I'd like to use a httpMockDriver instead of the real driver because the external API might be down, slow or even broken and I don't want to break the build.

At the moment I'm doing something like this:

```
<?php
namespace MyAwesome\TestBundle\DependencyInjection;

class MyAwesomeTestExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new       
                     FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $environment = //get environment
        if ($environment == 'test') {
            $loader->load('services_mock.yml');         
        } else {
            $loader->load('services.yml');          
        }
    }
}
```

This works for now, but will break for sure. So, is there a more elegant/solid way to change the HTTPDriver dynamically?

Comment: Why do you think it will break?

Comment: Keeping track of two different yml files ... someone will for sure forget to modify one of the files while changing a dependency

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally found a solution that looks solid to me. As of Symfony 2.4 you can use the expression syntax: [Using the Expression Language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language)

So I configured my service this way.

```
service.yml
parameters:
  httpDriver.class:       HTTP\Driver\Driver
  httpMockDriver.class:   HTTP\Driver\MockDriver
  myAwesomeService.class: My\Awesome\Service
service:
  myAwesomeService:
    class:        "%myAwesomeService.class%"
    arguments:    
      - "@=service('service_container').get('kernel.environment') == 'test'? service('httpMockDriver) : service('httpDriver)"
```

This works for me.

Comment: just a bit of upgrade to that - you can use `parameter('key')` to get parameter inside expression, no need to do it using container; and 2nd - to get container, you can just use `container` variable; details are here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language

Comment: The link is deprecated. Here's the right one: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html

Comment: I was hoping to use an expression for `class` instead of `arguments` but it doesn't work, any way to get that behavior?